# MAMP mysql command line working but not displaying info and I keep getting empty prompt arrow after commands

Tags: mysql, database, command-line, terminal, mamp

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3
Server version: 5.5.34 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases
    -> show databases
    ->
```

This is very strange, I don't think I have ever had this problem and I cannot find anything about it on the net nor here.

I recently purchased MAMP and installed it on my system. I changed the global PATH to point to the MAMP mysql and was able to connect to mysql via terminal and so I got the "mysql>" prompt on my terminal, no problems there.

However, **when I ask for certain things like "show databases" or "show tables", all I get in return is an empty prompt, in other words nothing but an empty arrow "->".**

I checked phpAdmin and everything is there, nothing seems missing (I have a lot of databases that I imported from previous mysql installations), I should be getting a list of all databases back as I AM connected to that exact same server.

**I also confirmed it via status ("status" and "help" commands for some reason work fine and they output the info) and mysql IS up and running and IS the MAMP installation.** So I don't see any reason why it should not be displaying the databases or tables etc.

Also, **what is weird is that my commands and queries ARE bieng executed and work, however I get no output reply from the terminal command prompt.**

If I create a database, all I get back in return on the prompt ids "->". The database gets created but I have to verify it by way of phpAdmin because, again "show databases" does not seem to work. Pretty much queries seem to work fine but I have no way of verifying through the mysql shell. Anybody ever encounter this problem? I have absolutely no idea of what could be causing this. I have already reinstalled mamp and mysql twice and even reverted to a previous mysql install that I had and still the same issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You aren't typing a semicolon at the end of the query:

```
mysql> show databases;
```